Is God Ever in Two Places at Once?
Are there any instances, ideally in Tanakh, where God's physical manifestation of Himself is present in two separate locations at once? Or more poignantly, are there instances of God speaking/prophesying to two separate people in two different places at once?
As an example to flesh out what I'm trying to get at here, in reading the account of the Egel Hazahav (the Golden Calf), I was struck by how God seems to discuss the ongoing crisis only from afar to Moshe, but never says anything while it's ongoing to Aaron (who is a prophet in his own right) as if He was present on Har Sinai but not in the camp (which of course does not theologically fit with God's omnipresence)(and I understand this is not the only possible reading). Got me wondering if there's any instances of the opposite- where God is clearly speaking/prophesying to two people separately (like two different conversations) but simultaneously, or barring that clearly in two places doing two different things at once.

Every Egyptian's house at midnight?

If Aharon was sinning, is it so surprising that God didn't want to talk directly to him then?

@DoubleAA Aharon was sinning!? Chas Veshalom

Can you explain the purpose of this question? The instinct is to answer that Hashem is beyond time, beyond space, and unlimited, as can be demonstrated in countless ways. What are you specifically getting at or trying to prove/solve with this question?

In a time of plague, the Angel of Death is everywhere at once (Berakhot 4b).  If angels can, so can God.  In quantum mechanics, particles can be in two places at the same time.  If particles can, so can God.

@RabbiKaii You don't think Aaron was sinning? I'd be interested that if your child was Aaron in the story, and people brought your child the gold to make an idol, whether you would advise your child to make the idol. In the same way I would ask parents who say Jacob never sinned by stealing the birthright of they would encourage their own kids to do the same thing

@Aaron Given that they killed Chur for rebuking them, Aharon realised they would kill him too if he rebuked them or refused to cooperate. This would have been terrible as killing both a priest and a prophet would have forced the Jewish people into exile (see Eicha 2:20), so he did anything he could to buy time in a way that didn't lead to his death, and Hashem clearly demonstrated that He approved of Aharon's actions - a good leader putting the people first. I have the Midrash and Eitz Yosef to back me up on this, but it's all clear from a close reading of the episode.

@RabbiKaii What you said read to me as "he sinned, but only to save his own life." I would agree with that assessment, and I might advise my children to do the same thing. But I wouldn't tell them it's absolutely the correct thing and there's no sin or moral ambiguity

@Aaron or, "he sinned, but it was the right thing to do". That's a can of worms, no?

@RabbiKaii That's life, no?

@RabbiKaii ובאהרן התאנף ה' מאד להשמידו ואתפלל גם בעד אהרן בעת ההוא

To clarify my question further, of course God can be in two places at once. But the question is, is there an example of His choosing to be. Don't really think Makat Bechorot counts, as 1) He/the Destroyer/Angel of Death or whatever passes by houses, suggesting continual movement of a single presence, and 2) it's really the same action being done in the places, so don't think it qualifies either way.

Also of course peshat is that Aharon sinned, but not really at the heart of my question either way.

I saw a very good explaination WHY NOT because if it was one would think there are two Gdly biengs Chas VeShalom

@Aaron it's also worth mentioning that if the people had killed Aharon, they would have been severely punished or destroyed. So choosing to take part in the golden calf may have saved the Jewish people. Besides, he purposefully stalled the process in the hope that they would see Moshe come down before it was complete.

@EthanLeonard Thousands of people were killed over the golden calf as it was. The actual right answer seems to be to have not made the calf at all

@Aaron that wasn't the metric of the discussion as I understood it. Rather, it was whether you would have been proud of your child doing the same thing. So if someone's child went against everything they stood for to try to save the Jewish people, I think they could very well be proud. That metric js not about whether in hindsight it would have worked out better. Which, by the way, it may have actually, because again, destroying the entire Jewish people in retribution would have been worse. Or something like what happened after Zechariah was killed.

See Bamidbar 11:25-26

This question feels like it's rooted in something bordering on if not already deep in the realm of apikorsus.

@Yehuda- out of curiosity, is the apikorsut side you're concerned about God being in two places at once, or not being in two places at once?

Yes, and no.
Answering the title and the first sentence specifically, the Shechina, Hashem's dwelling in the spiritual and physical worlds, can certainly be in multiple places at once.
Avot 3:6 demonstrates that Hashem will be present among every gathering of 10 Jews*, and even 5, 3 and 1 Jew(s), and brings pasukim to source these claims. Shemot 20:21 is the most striking:

בכל המקום אשר אזכיר את שמי אבא אליך וברכתיך
In every place where I cause My Name to be mentioned I will come unto
you and bless you

Which Sforno, Ohr HaChaim and others explain means that Hashem, when He promised to "dwell among us" (Shemot 25:8), initially meant dwell in more places than just between the Keruvim, such as within every Jew.
There is also the concept that Hashem's Presence sits among 3 judges when they judge. This is also brought in Avot 3:6, with a source in Tehillim.
That's the yes. The no is brought by Rabban Gamliel to a כופר in Sanhedrin 39a:

א"ל כופר לר"ג אמריתו כל בי עשרה שכינתא שריא כמה שכינתא איכא קרייה
לשמעיה מחא ביה באפתקא א"ל אמאי על שמשא בביתיה דכופר א"ל שמשא אכולי
עלמא ניחא ומה שמשא דחד מן אלף אלפי רבוא שמשי דקמי קודשא בריך הוא ניחא
לכולי עלמא שכינתא דקב"ה על אחת כמה וכמה
The emperor said to Rabban Gamliel: You say that the Divine Presence (Shechina)
dwells in any place where there are ten adult male Jews. He asked,
sarcastically: How many Shechinas are there? Rabban Gamliel
summoned the servant of the emperor and hit him on his neck
[be’appatka]. Rabban Gamliel said to him: Why did you allow the sun to
enter the house of the emperor? The emperor said to him: The sun rests
upon all the world; no one can prevent it from shining. Rabban Gamliel
said to him: And if the sun, which is one of ten thousand attendants
that are before the Holy One, Blessed be He, rests upon all the world,
the Divine Presence of the Holy One, Blessed be He, all the more so
rests upon the world. [Steinsaltz trans. and commentary]

So, it's not actually true that He's in multiple places at once, in the sense that He splits up into multiple parts, chas veshalom, but that does not preclude Him from shining the Light of His Presence, as it were, into wherever is zoche, and desirable to Him.

* See also Tanya Iggeret HaKodesh 23. Also brought in halacha, e.g. Shulchan Aruch HaRav. Related is that the Shechina rests on the hands of Cohanim during Birchat HaCohanim. There are many examples like this.

According to the Rambam, Hashem is incorporeal. Hashem cannot manifest physically at all, even in one location (Intro to Heleq):

היסוד השלישי שלילת הגשמות ממנו. וזהו שנאמין כי האחד הזה שזכרנו, אינו
גוף ולא כוח בגוף, ולא ישיגוהו מאורעות הגופים כמו התנועה והמנוחה
והמשכן, לא מצד עצמות ולא במקרה. ולכן שללו ממנו החכמים ז"ל החיבור
והפירוד. ואמרו (חגיגה טו.) אין למעלה לא ישיבה ולא עמידה, לא עורף ולא
עפוי. כלומר: לא פירוד ולא עורף. והוא חיבור "ולא עפוי" מלשון "ועפו בכתף
פלשתים", כלומר ידחפו אותם בכתף להתחברם בהם. ואמר הנביא "ואל מי תדמיוני
ואשוה יאמר קדוש". אילו היה גוף, היה דומה לגופים, וכל מה שבא בכתבי
הקודש שמתארים אותו בתוארי הגופות, כמו ההליכה והעמידה והישיבה והדיבור
וכיוצא בזה - הכל דרך השאלה. וכן אמרו ז"ל (ברכות לא ע"ב) "דיברה תורה
כלשון בני אדם". וכבר דיברו החכמים בזה העניין הרבה. והיסוד השלישי הזה
הוא מורה עליו מה שנאמר "כי לא ראיתם כל תמונה". כלומר: לא הישגתם אותו
בעל תמונה, לפי שהוא, כמו שזכרנו, אינו גוף ולא כוח בגוף.
The Third Fundamental principle: We are to believe that he is
incorporeal, that His unity is physical neither potentially nor
actually. None of the attributes of matter can be predicated of Him,
neither motion, nor rest for example. They cannot refer to Him
accidentally or essentially. That is why our sages denied Him
composition and separation, and said : “On high there is neither
sitting nor standing, neither want nor weariness” (Hagigah 15a), i.e.,
neither composition nor separation, and said: “On High there is
neither sitting nor standing, neither want nor weariness” (Hagigah
15a), i.e., neither composition nor separation, as the Biblical usage
of these words attests. The prophet asked: “To whom can you compare
God, whom might he resemble?” (Is. 40:18). If He were a body, He would
be like other bodies. Whenever Scripture describes Him im corporeal
terms like walking, standing, sitting, speaking, and the like, it
speaks metaphorically. Thus our sages said: “The Torah speaks in human
language” (Berakhot 31b). This third fundamental principle is taught
in the Biblical verse: “You have seen no image” (Deut. 4:15). This
verse means to say, one cannot conceive of Him as one would a Baal
image, since, as we have shown, He has no body at all, actually or
potentially.

This is not a limitation of Hashem, but a limit of our physical world.

I am aware. Rambam should take that up with the peshat of the Torah. In any event, rejecting the premise of the question is not a particularly helpful answer.

That's a heavy claim zaq, please source it so we can see if you'd explained it correctly. Also I agree that it's not good practice to reject the premise of the question - that's the kind of thing best left to comments

@ezzi386 "Rambam should take that up with the peshat of the Torah" he does... see how the Rambam describes the third fundamental of Jewish belief

@RabbiKaii explaining why the premise of a question is false seems to be an accepted variety of answer around here: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4109/2394

הרי מפרש בתורה ובנביאים שאין הקדוש ברוך הוא גוף וגויה שנאמר ( דברים ד לט יהושע ב יא) "כי ה' אלהיכם הוא אלהים בשמים ממעל ועל הארץ מתחת". והגוף לא יהיה בשני מקומות. ונאמר (דברים ד טו) "כי לא ראיתם כל תמונה". ונאמר (ישעיה מ כה) "ואל מי תדמיוני ואשוה". ואלו היה גוף היה דומה לשאר גופים

I'd like to suggest a possible viewpoint that God is ALWAYS in two places at once. Because sometimes scripture gives the impression that God is somewhere or doing X, and you find out a few verses later that it's an Angel speaking on God's behalf. For example the Pillar of Fire by Night and Pillar of Cloud by Day was both God and not God? So I would argue that even when there's a manifestation of God, whether it's an Angel or some other form, God is also somewhere else in that moment.

God is everywhere. He cannot be "in" any place at once, as that would require locality.

It's not good practice to reject the premise of the question in an answer - that's the kind of thing best left to comments
